# combining 2 identical tables into one before executing a query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, data-analysis

i have to combine 2 identical tables into one before running my query or select statement
Let me explain in detail - 
Basically i have a stored procedure which gets executed once a day at the end of the day say 12:00 and then it deletes all entries//records from table T1(which has millions of records)as its no longer required as the stored procedure got me what i was interested in. 
The problem now is sometimes, i need data to be stored to be used next day for the query in stored procedure to give me correct result. So before deletion i save the records of interest in another table so that next day i can merge or combine this data with table t1 generated that day and run my query.
So how do i go about this?
Use union? join?
I tried union like this

```
select * from t1
union all
select * from prevT1
```

but then i get this error
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Since i have created identical table both have same columns.
Is the problem because one of the column is  identity column??
i faced this when doing insert into prevT1 select * from t2 and i had to manually write column list.

### EDITTED

Create statement looks like this
CREATE TABLE t1(
    [DataUno] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID] nvarchar NULL,
    ...
     )

Comment: List all the columns explicitly instead of using `select *`.

Comment: Can you show us the CREATE TABLE statement for these 2 tables?  Also, what database are you using (MySQL, PostgresSQL, etc)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Too many columns in table and i need to replicate it to both the table and then again outside perform my query